# Wifi slows Ubuntu to a halt after waking from sleep

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-netbook, sleep, ralink, msi

The computer is a MSI Wind U100+ Netbook with Ralink RT2700E. There was a similar issue I was able to correct in 10.04 by adding some blacklist drivers in /etc/modprob.d but the issue then only meant I could not connect to internet after waking. Now it causes everything to slow to unusable as it tries to connect even if I turn off wifi and I am forced to hard reboot the machine. As I am running Conky I can see the process eating up the CPU - it is something like kirqsofd or some such thing. I apologize I do not remember the exact name of the process but I'm sure that is close.

I do not believe installing WICD is a solution as that also did not completely work in 10.04. It is something to do with the drivers I am certain.

## In 10.04 This is to fix wifi on the MSI Wind with the Ralink RT2700E.

blacklist rt2800pci
blacklist rt2800lib
blacklist rt2x00pci
blacklist rt2x00lib

saved as /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rt2800.conf

But adding this in 12.04 means no wireless at all. :(

Answer (score 1):

I set the following alias in .bashrc (actually in file called alias.sh and then sourcing it in .bashrc)...

```
alias netre='sudo service network-manager restart'
```

In this way, I can wake up and just type `netre` (network reset) in the terminal and the connection resets.